# Silverstripe session variables only display when page is refreshed

Tags: php, silverstripe

I asked this question on the Silverstripe forum originally. 
http://www.silverstripe.org/data-model-questions/show/21293

I am trying to get a variable from various google location ads to change the phone number depending on the ?number=xxx from the ad.

The number displays a default value unless the page is refreshed, then the variable value is displayed.

Is there a better way of doing this that will display the variable number without the need for a page refresh?

In page.ss

```
<% if phonenumber %>$phonenumber <% else %>0800 xxx xxx<% end_if %>
```

In page.php

```
public function Phonenumber() {
 ob_start();
  if (!isset($_SESSION)) {
   @session_start();
  }
  if (!isset($_SESSION['number'])){
   $phonenumber = $_GET['number'];
   $_SESSION['number'] = $phonenumber;
  }
 ob_end_flush();
return strip_tags (Session::get ('number'));
}
```

Comment: may I ask what defines.php is for and why you have excluded that code into defines.php?

Comment: why fiddling with the session? a simple "return $_GET['number']" should be fine, no? (you should escape it for security reasons, of course)

Comment: defines.php is used to set $phonenumber as the variable '?number=123456' from the googel location ad. When users land on the site they need to have the phonenumber set to whatever their location is, and this must not change for the duration of the visit. Is why I am fiddling with session. This works but only when the page is refreshed.

Comment: still, why are you putting it into the file defines.php? why not just run the code inside the function Phonenumber()?

Comment: There isn't ay specific reason other than legacy from a static site which is being made via Silverstripe. But isn't that as wide as it is long? Anyway, I have added the code to the Phonenumber() function to remove the include all together, still has the same result - only working on page refresh.

Comment: would you mind updating your code in your question to the latest coude, so I can have a look at it

Comment: Just check if query string var is set and return, and if not, check if session var is set and return, otherwise return null.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as Benjamin Smith suggested, you can just return the number you got out of $_GET
try the following:

**php**:

```
public function Phonenumber() {
    if (isset($_GET['number']))
        $number = $_GET['number'];
    else
        $number = Session::get('number');
    $number = strip_tags($number);
    Session::set('number', $number);
    if ($number)
        return $number;
    else 
        return '0800 xxx xxx';
}
```

**template**:

```
$Phonenumber
```

also, I am pretty sure you do not need to use ob_start() nor do you need to start the session (silverstripe has started a session at that point already)

Comment: That is working as intended. Thanks for your perserverance here, but the goal posts have been moved slightly... I now have a few pages that are aimed at organic listings, where no variable is used. But I still need to get the local numbers in the session. I have created a new $StaticNumber textfield where I enter the number. In the header.ss I have this `<% if phonenumber %>$phonenumber <% else %><% if StaticNumber %>$StaticNumber <% else %>0800 xxx xxx<% end_if %><% end_if %>`. How do I set $StaticNumber as a session variable? @zauberfisch